# I want to show the featured products first,then it should be show the rest of products order by id desc

Tags: php, mysql

```
my code is as follow...


$sql="
select * 
  from ads 
 where category = '$category_id' 
   and action = '1' 
 order 
    by feature desc";
```

At this stage only those products showing on top who have greatest feature.now it should be show the rest of products according their id desc.
what syntax i have to add in this query please suggest.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from ads 
where category = '$category_id' 
and action = '1'
order by feature desc, id desc
```

Comment: @Divakarcool You Welcome :) by the way, you can mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort part of items one way and second part of items another way, you have to make two queries - one with *order by feature desc* and second one with *order by id desc*